# How to search for strings in text and replace with links in php

Tags: php, regex, twitter

I am currently pulling a twitter feed into my website and displaying the contents on the frontpage. 
All I want to be able to do is replace any content that is hashtags or Twitter usernames with links.

I attempted to do this using preg_replace but I was having an issues with building the link to use as the replacement as I was unsure as to how to reference and insert the matched pattern.  Here is what i ahve so far (unfinished). Can anybody help me?

Thanks!

```
<?php 
foreach($tweets as $tweet) { ?>
  <?php 
    $pattern = '@([A-Za-z0-9_]+)';
    $replacement = "<a href=''>" . . "</a>";
    $regex_text = preg_replace($pattern, );

  ?>
  <div class="tweet2">
    <img src="images/quotes.png" />
    <p><?php echo $tweet[text]; ?></p>
  </div>
<?php }
?>
```

Comment: What exactly are you “unsure” about? How to reference matched parts is described in the PHP docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$regex_text = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $input_text);
```

That's the correct way to use a preg_replace, `$input_text` is the variable with the text you want to replace stuff from.

That aside:

```
$pattern="/@([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/"; //can't be sure if this will work w/o an example of a input string.
$replacement= "<a href=''>$1</a>";  //$1 is what you capture between `()` in the pattern.
```

Comment: @funkyjimbob glad it helped, please remember to accept the answer ^^

Answer (score 1):

With those parenthesis, you're defining a *capture group*. When you use a capture group in your pattern, you can reference those using either `\\n` or `$n`, starting from 0 to 99, in order.

So your replacement would be:

`$replacement = "<a href='http://twitter.com/$1'>$1</a>";`

If you have more capture groups, you'll have higher numbers.

Check out [the manual entry](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), the `$replacement` parameter for more information.